# ERROR in node_modules/@types/node/globals.global.d.ts(1,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'globalThis'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 7.2.6, angular-cli 7.3.9 and typescript 3.2.4. I am getting error when building angular app
ERROR in node_modules/@types/node/globals.global.d.ts(1,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'globalThis'.
Can someone please let me know the probable cause for this error.

I see globalThis is introduced in typescript 3.4; but considering i am using typescript 3.2.4, not sure what is causing the above, and how globalThis module is being referred to access variables.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks Vishal Kedar for your response. Your response helped me to think and explore further.
After i changed "@types/node": "10.14.0", the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 7):

Update the `package.json` file for the below module

```json
"@types/node": "^14.0.4"
```

Comment: Thanks.. This error is coming with above suggested change.. ERROR in node_modules/@types/node/process.d.ts(298,17): error TS2687: All declarations of 'traceDeprecation' must have identical modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! as @vishal said:

```
npm install @types/node@14.0.4 --saveDev
```

works perfectly for me too

Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

I had so error code when i compiled my project.

> ERROR in node_modules/@types/node/globals.global.d.ts(1,44): error
> TS2304: Cannot find name 'globalThis'.

In my case :
I opened this file `globals.global.d.ts`
and it has so line

`declare var global: NodeJS.Global & typeof globalThis;`

and i  commented this line and problem was solved